# How to merge two strings in python?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I need to merge strings together to create one string. For example the strings for "hello" that need to be combined are:
[H----], [-E---], [--LL-], and [----O]

This is the current code I have to make the letters appear in the first place.

```
display_string = "[" + "".join([x if x == letter else "-" for x in word]) + "]"
```

How would I go about making strings such as
[H----], [HE---], [HELL-], and finally [HELLO]?

Comment: Can you explain what `letter` is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this helps in the way you wanted, but this works.  The problem is that we don't really have a string replacement.  A list of chars might work better for you until the final assembly.

```
string_list = [
    'H----',
    '-E---',
    '--LL-',
    '----O'
]

word_len = len(string_list[0])
display_string = word_len*'-'
for word in string_list:
    for i in range(word_len):
        if word[i].isalpha():
            display_string = display_string[:i] + word[i] + display_string[i+1:]
    print '[' + display_string + ']'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think I see where you are going with this.

We define a word like "hello," then we iterate over all unique letters in "hello" and we get your `display_string`s. Then your question is about how to merge them back together?

```
word = "HELLO"
all_display_strings = ["[" + "".join([x if x == letter else "-" for x in word]) + "]" for letter in word]
# now merge the list of lists
length = len(all_display_strings[0])-2 # -2 for the opening and closing bracket
merged_display_strings = ['-']*length

for i in range(0, length):
        for j in range(0, len(all_display_strings)):
            if (all_display_strings[j][i+1] != '-'):
                merged_display_strings[i] = all_display_strings[j][i+1]


print(''.join(merged_display_strings))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your strings are in a list `all_strings`

```
all_strings = ["[H----]", "[-E---]", "[--LL-]", "[----O]"]
# clean them
all_strings = map(lambda x:x.strip()[1:-1], all_strings)

# Let's create a list for the characters in the final string(for easy mutating)
final_string = ['' for _ in xrange(max(map(len, all_strings)))]

for single in all_strings:
    for i, char in enumerate(single):
        if char != '-': final_string[i]=char

print "[" + ''.join(final_string) + "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings = 'h----', '-e---', '--ll-', '----o'
letterSoups = [ [ (p, c) for (p, c) in enumerate(s) if c != '-' ]
    for s in strings ]
result = list('-----')
for soup in letterSoups:
  for p, c in soup:
    result[p] = c
print ''.join(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "[H----], [-E---], [--LL-],  [----O]"

print(''.join(re.findall(r'\w', s)))

HELLO
```