# Merging strings in python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I'm making a hangman game and I need to update the table showing the correct letters. So far the program prints this

```
Enter a word: hello
[-----] You have 6 guesses left, enter a letter: h
Correct!
[H----] You have 6 guesses left, enter a letter: e
Correct!
[-E---] You have 6 guesses left, enter a letter: l
Correct!
[--LL-] You have 6 guesses left, enter a letter: o
Correct!
[----O] You have 6 guesses left, enter a letter:
```

What I need the program to do is combine the strings for example [H----] --> [HE---] and so on. How would I do this? As well as end the game when there are no more dashes left.

An example of what I want the program to look like is

```
[H----]
[HE---]
```

the program also has to work in a random order for example...

```
[----O]
[-E--O]
[HE--O]
[HELLO]
```

This is my code so far

[image: My code so far]

Comment: Can you show your code, that way SO can help.

Comment: You did a good job explaining how your program should work. But could you please show your code attempt at this? Please be explicit about what parts of your code are giving you issues.

Comment: Post the actual code, it's easier. Not the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two strings in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137198/how-to-merge-two-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the string to be guessed and show either the letter, if that letter was already guessed or '_' in case it hasn't.

```
In [127]: s = "Apple"

In [128]: already_guessed = ['p', 'e']

In [129]: '[' + ''.join([letter if letter in already_guessed else '_' for letter in s]) + ']'
Out[129]: '[_pp_e]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of recomputing display_string with "-", use the previous value of display_string. Note: You need to offset the index of display_string because of your brackets.

```
display_string = "[" + "".join([x if x == letter else display_string[i + 1] for i, x in enumerate(word)]) + "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at an answer, wrote this up before you put up your code, so it may not be what you're looking for, but it works.

```
def hangman():
    answer = raw_input('Enter a word: ') # getting the word
    guesses = 6 # number of starting guesses
    word = '[' + '-'*len(answer) + ']' # this is the string of interest to be printed
    while True:
        print word, 'You have %d guesses left' % guesses,
        if guesses == 0 or '-' not in word: break
            # game finishes if word is guessed, or guesses run out
        letter = raw_input(', enter a letter: ') # guess a letter
        guesses -= 1 # decrease number of guesses by 1 each time
        for index, char in enumerate(answer): # iterate through all letters in answer
            if letter == char: # check if guessed letter is in the answer
                wordlist = list(word) # representing the word as a list to allow mutation
                wordlist[index+1] = letter # mutate the correctly guessed letter
                word = ''.join(wordlist) # recombining the list into a string
```